can connect to postgres using PSQL but cannot connect today using python psycopg2
I am on a VPN.  I can successfully connect to a Postgres server using PSQL
/opt/homebrew/bin/psql postgres://myuser:mypass@mydbhost.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/postgres

However, although this was working up until now for many weeks,  today  I rebooted my Mac and rejoined VPN, and now using Python/psycopg2 in any of my programs breaks:
(I am using Anaconda Spyder)
Today suddenly I get an error. It was working until now.
The Python connector code is simple:
config = load_config()   # comes from database.ini file
print(config)   # when I print it out, I can verify it is correct
conn = db_conn.connect(config) 
cur = conn.cursor() 

Here is my iPython console output:
FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/python/export_query_to_csv_template.py:50
    cur = conn.cursor()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Restarting kernel...

Now if I run in on the command line outside of the Spyder environment I get this:
12:01:31 wdavis $ python ./python/export_query_to_csv_template.py
FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wdavis/./python/export_query_to_csv_template.py", line 50, in <module>
    cur = conn.cursor()   
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
zsh: trace trap  python ./python/export_query_to_csv_template.py

But once again I can see that my config dictionary is correct and I do have the user name specified.  This is baffling.
Any ideas?   I can see my user name is specified but it is saying it is not.  Should I rebuild a package or try a different Python interpreter?   Confused by PSQL working and this is not.

What is the confusion, with psql you are going through libpq directly, with the Python code you are going through Python --> psycopg2 --> libpq. Since the former works and the latter does not the problem is in your Python code and/or psycopg2. Since you have not seen fit include the Python code there is not really much else to say.

What do you mean, the Python code is in the question.


It was not when I commented. 2) The relevant parts in export_query_to_csv_template.py are still hazy. Since the error is FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet there needs to be more information about what  load_config() in config = load_config() is actually doing and returning.


load_config() returns a dictionary.  It was working for many weeks until today.  It returns {'host': 'myhostdb.postgres.database.azure.com', 'database': 'postgres', 'user': 'myuser', 'password': 'mypass'} After I rebooted my Mac and joined my VPN today, it has stopped working.  Looking for a solution.

This turned out to be a Spyder and Conda Env issue.
I carefully studied the debug output when the kernel failed in Spyder console.  It was using inconsistent files in the trace.  What I did was define a new conda environment for my Python3.12 and I activated that environment.  Then I installed all needed modules (psycopg2, etc.) and also I needed to do this:
conda install -c conda-forge spyder-kernels=3.0 .  I also needed to go to Anaconda Navigator and connect it to my new environment, and then I installed Spyder in it.  Finally when I launched the "new" spyder I made sure I was fully synced by also doing conda install -c conda-forge psycopg2
Finally after all this preparatory work in creating a new Conda env and activating it, and getting all the needed modules into it, then the connect code ran as expected.

Then the answer to the problem is use a less convoluted system. IPython comes to mind.
